# Best way to render a web of interconnecting elements in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, data-visualization

I'm looking for the best way to render a web of interconnected elements in HTML5.

For example, let's say I have the following documents:

```
firstObject = { other1: secondObject; other2: thirdObject }
secondObject = {other1: thirdObject}
thirdObject = {other1: firstObject}
```

I would like to render these as, for example, circles, with lines connecting between the documents who reference each other.

I'm not sure what the best way to implement something like this: do I use canvas? If so, how would I go about laying out the canvas properly given the above data only (how do you position elements so they can have lines drawn between them given their interconnections?)

I'm not looking for code, merely a suggestion of where and how to start.

Comment: I would go with canvas nowadays but I don't have personal experience with it.  Just seen what it can do.

Comment: complex, but good question. I would go for something along the lines of calculating angles of elements and distance, creating a 1px wide `div` with the correct angle to go between elements, also for distance.

Comment: More info needed :) Can you describe the schema of your data and their relationships?

Comment: @markE Very simple, just one links to another (or multiple others), the objects would need to be positioned properly to be linked together with lines without intersecting with other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) to do this job.

Here was the result: [image: EVE Online System Map]

You can achieve something like this by making a json file with nodes (any data can be in them, in this case, just title) and connections (links, between indexes in the node array). D3 then loads this json file and with a bit of code can render it in a [Force Directed Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642).

As you can see, these are systems from the popular game [EVE Online](http://eveonline.com) - I took their database dump, and wrote a C# program to generate this sort of json data from the system data in their database.

Answer (score 1):

For something geometrical that doesn't need a lot of interaction, and from a design point of view shouldn't represent a lot of textual information, `canvas` is the most definitely the way to go. We're now past the days when `canvas` was still beta - now it's supported by all the major browsers.

I would start by thinking about the variables in your data. How many degrees of freedom? How would I vary the representation of each variable? For example, if you have a (numeric) property of each document you would like to show, such as the size of the document, you might vary the size of the shape representing the document.

You might also want to think about how to position your elements. What would the x and y coordinates represent for each point? If you don't have anything meaningful that might be represented by the coordinates, how would you want to arrange the points randomly - in other words, what would you want the picture to look like?

Once you've got these design problems figured out, the rest is a matter of learning to code `canvas`: take a look at the tutorials offered by Mozilla's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial) and the ever popular [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html).

Comment: I might actually use SVG for this as well - thanks for the links and insight.